# How to assign a macro that uses parameter to a button in excel

Tags: excel, vba, button, parameters, evaluate

A client requested that I add the buttons as shown in image 1 below.

[image]

There can be from 1 to 100 sets of buttons. The reason is unimportant to this question.

Seeing as they have practically identical functions I need to assign them but somehow have the row number available as a parameter or variable or something.

```
Private Sub Edit_CVR_Row(Btn_row As Integer)
```

At the generation of the buttons the row number is part of a for loop and known and this is how I assign the macro

```
With btn
    .OnAction = "'Edit_CVR_Row """ & Btn_row & "'"
    .Caption = "Edit"
    .Name = "Sheet1_" + Str(Btn_row) + "_Edit"  
End With
```

This is the error I get

[image: Error 1]

There is a similar solution that uses the Evaluate function with similar results.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be `"'Edit_CVR_Row " & Btn_row & "'"` but note that this will not work in an xlsb format file. If the row number relates to the location of the button, there are other ways.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
 
I get the error: --
 
Cannot run Macro 'Master.xlsm!'Edit_CVR_Row 6''. The macro may not be available or all macros may be disabled.-- 

Master.xlsm is the file name. The row number does indeed relate to the button location and I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: In. your macro you can refer to `activesheet.buttons(application.caller).topleftcell.row` to get the row number of the button clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

activesheet.buttons(application.caller).topleftcell.row

Thank you for this Rory, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you open your Excel file, is there a yellowish band on top of your cells asking you to activate the macros ? If so, you should accept it before running your macro, otherwise you will receive that kind of notification.

It is also possible that macros are not activated in your Excel, you can check it by going in the File tab --> Options --> Trust center --> Macro setting, and then you will have to select the option you want.